# Why I get spikes during training with vanilla gradient descent?

Tags: neural-networks, classification, optimization, loss-functions, gradient-descent

I developed my own NN toolbox, and it seems it works fine.
But I am not sure why I get these spikes in my loss during training:

[image]

I a training for a classification task of 2 inputs and 2 classes, similar to the XOR function. The network has 4 hidden units with tanh. The learning rate is constant at 0.001, without regularization.

I have read that the spikes are due to the mini batch, but in my case, I use the whole dataset  for the update of the weights. So it does not apply. Just in case, I am using 1000 samples for training and 334 for testing.

I guess it might improve if I reduce the learning rate over time. Is it so?
What about momentum, might it help?

Also, why the spikes appear later during training?? and why they seem periodic??

My dataset and the predictions look like this:

[image]

Comment: Since this phenomenon appears in your self-implemented NN toolbox, the most likely cause is a bug. We can’t see the code, so any advice we could offer would be mere guesses. Compare your results to those of a high-quality, battle-tested library and work to systematically find any discrepancies.

Comment: can recommend me one toolbox to compare?

Comment: Keras, Torch and Tensorflow are widely used.